# dynamically fetching data from mongoose

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I need to fetch data from the MongoDB collection after the user clicks the id properties of the document

[frontend][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmW1N.jpg

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const ViewVehicles = () => {
  const [vehicles, setVehicles] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchvehicles = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/headofDeployement/registerVehicle");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setVehicles(json);
      }
    };

    fetchvehicles();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container ">
      <div className="row ">
        <div className="col justify-content-center align-center">
          <h4>Vehicles Registered</h4>
          {vehicles &&
            vehicles.map((vehicle) => (
              <ul key={vehicle._id}>
                <a href="" className="text-danger">
                  {vehicle._id}
                </a>
              </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewVehicles;
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I need to redirect the user to another page and show all information about a vehicle or in that document id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you should use the `Link` component you imported from `react-router-dom`.

For further reading and methodology of how this use case can be handled, check: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: I want to show all field values in the document after the user clicks the id of the document